# Order of $a$ is $10$ What is order of $b^2ab^{-1}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Order of $a$ is $10$

> What is order of $b^2ab^{-1}$?

I am confused here,how can i find order of $b^2ab^{-1}$ just with this little data. please provide me a hint.

Thankyou

Comment: The correct question probably is: *What is the order of $bab^{-1}$? Perhaps you copied it wrongly.

Answer (score 3):

There is not enough info. If $b=e,$ then the order is clearly $10.$ If $b=a^{-1},$ the order is $1.$ If $b$ has order $2,$ then we want the order of $ab,$ which can vary since $(ab)^n = ababab\dots ab$ does not show any signs of cancellation.

The order of $bab^{-1}$ is $10,$ but I suppose you believe there's no typo.